# How do I add a GROUP_CONCAT to my UNION query?

Tags: mysql

I have the following query that works fine to get the correct emails, giving the following results: 
- user1@company.com
- user2@company.com
- etc

Question: How do I add a MySQL **GROUP_CONCAT** function so the results will be separated by commas:
- user1@company.com,user2@company.com,etc

Here is just a part of my Union query:

### - when I feed it a Ticket Number, it checks the Ticket Type value on the ticket & returns just those Users who have that Type checked in the back-end table.

```
SELECT CONCAT(tblemailaction.uea_User, "@company.com") AS User_email,                 tblemailaction.uea_ADSL
FROM tblemailaction, tbltickets, tbltickettype
WHERE tbltickets.ttType = tbltickettype.ttDesc
 AND tbltickettype.ttID = tblemailaction.uea_ADSL
 AND ttNum = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#url.id#">


UNION ALL


SELECT CONCAT(tblemailaction.uea_User, "@company.com") AS User_email,          tblemailaction.uea_ADSL_INSTALL
FROM tblemailaction, tbltickets, tbltickettype
WHERE tbltickets.ttType = tbltickettype.ttDesc
 AND tbltickettype.ttID = tblemailaction.uea_ADSL_INSTALL
 AND ttNum = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#url.id#">

UNION ALL


SELECT CONCAT(tblemailaction.uea_User, "@company.com") AS User_email, tblemailaction.uea_Cabling
FROM tblemailaction, tbltickets, tbltickettype
WHERE tbltickets.ttType = tbltickettype.ttDesc
 AND tbltickettype.ttID = tblemailaction.uea_Cabling
 AND ttNum = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#url.id#">


UNION ALL


SELECT CONCAT(tblemailaction.uea_User, "@company.com") AS User_email, tblemailaction.uea_Calix
FROM tblemailaction, tbltickets, tbltickettype
WHERE tbltickets.ttType = tbltickettype.ttDesc
 AND tbltickettype.ttID = tblemailaction.uea_Calix
 AND ttNum = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#url.id#">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, note that `GROUP_CONCAT` function is limited by the value of the `max_allowed_packet` variable, which is typically set to 1048576 (i.e. 1MB). Of course, the value of this variable can be increased, but just be aware that there is a limitation.

The quick answer is to "wrap" your entire query in a set of parenthesis, and reference that as a rowsource in a query. Basically, turn your query into an "inline view".

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(v.User_email)
  FROM (
         /* your UNION ALL query here */
       ) q
```

---

To remove duplicates, you can use the DISTINCT keyword. To get the values in a particular sequence, you can use an ORDER BY clause.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT v.User_email ORDER BY v.User_email)
  FROM (
         /* your UNION ALL query here */
       ) q
```

Again, note that the length of the string returned by the `GROUP_CONCAT` function is limited by the value of `max_allowed_packet`.

---

**Follow-up Q:** How do I "Exclude" or filter out an email from the list.. for example: - If SESSION.kt_email = "one of the emails in the list" THEN remove from list

**A:** The quick answer is by example.  If you have a single email address you want to exclude, say `'foo'`, for the sake of this example:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( NULLIF(v.User_email,'foo') )
  FROM (
         /* your UNION ALL query here */
       ) q
```

The trick here is that we are replacing any value of `'foo'` with a `NULL`, and `GROUP_CONCAT` will "skip" any NULL values and exclude them from the return string.

The expression:

```
    NULLIF(v.User_email,'foo')
```

is shorthand for:

```
    IF(v.User_email='foo',NULL,v.User_email)
```

which is equivalent to (the more ANSI standard):

```
    CASE WHEN v.User_email = 'foo' THEN NULL ELSE v.User_email END
```

Of course you'd replace the literal `'foo'` (in my example) with whatever string value or expression that you'd want excluded.

Comment: spencer, that works great & I learned something new there..

One other thing.. How do I "Exclude" or filter out an email from the list.. for example:

- If SESSION.kt_email = "one of the emails in the list" THEN remove from list

Comment: @jlig: use an expression like `NULLIF(v.User_email,'foo')` inside the GROUP_CONCAT. My answer is updated with a followup.

Comment: I'm using this query on a ColdFusion page and not doing something right:

- This code below works if I "hard-code" the foo value..

    SELECT    GROUP_CONCAT( NULLIF( User_email,excluded_user@company.com))AS User_email
    FROM ( etc..

- But when I try to feed in my Session variable, I get all emails?
    <cfset foo = Session.kt_email>
    SELECT    GROUP_CONCAT( NULLIF( User_email,#foo#))AS User_email
    FROM ( etc..

Looks like an issue with the #foo# variable in MySQL? Not sure how to reference ColdFusion variables in the SELECT part..?

Comment: Wouldn't you just do somthing like ...  `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(NULLIF(v.User_email, <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#Session.kt_email#"> )) AS ...` ?  But then again, I'm not a ColdFusion guy; I'm just making a guess there. (ColdFusion shouldn't care where in the statement a query parameter goes, whether it's in an expression in the SELECT list or in an expression in the WHERE clause; other interfaces don't have limitations on where query parameters go.)

Comment: spencer, the following finally worked to filter out the "logged-in user"..
-----------------------
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(NULLIF(User_email, <cfqueryparam     cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#ARGUMENTS.kt_email#"> )) AS     User_email
    FROM ( etc..

-----------------------

But one last question: 
- Instead of returning a NULL (when there are no emails)
- I need it to return a default email value of "no-reply@company.com"

Comment: @jlig: one option is to use the `IFNULL()` function to wrap that whole mess of an expression, e.g.  `IFNULL( expr , 'foo')`. That says: if `expr` is NULL, then return `foo`, else return `expr`.  (That can also be written `if(expr IS NULL,'foo',expr)`. The big advantage of the `IFNULL` shorthand is that you don't have repeat `expr` twice.

Comment: Can I use the IFNULL( expr , 'foo') on "top" of my SELECT like this?

I tried
----------------------
IFNULL( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(NULLIF(User_email...etc
....
)q 
, 'no-reply@company.com')
----------------------
but get a MySQL error at the bottom of my query

Comment: Uh, no, the SELECT keyword is not part of the expression. The expression you want to wrap is the `GROUP_CONCAT(blah)`.  e.g. `SELECT IFNULL( GROUP_CONCAT(...) ,'foo') AS User_email FROM `

Comment: Ah.. got it.. that does it! Thanks again..
--------------------------
    SELECT IFNULL( GROUP_CONCAT(NULLIF(User_email, <cfqueryparam     cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#ARGUMENTS.kt_email#"> )), 'no-    reply@company.com') AS User_email